# String comparison to consider numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview

I am trying to sort nodes of a treeview with respect to their text property of course. The problem is that my comparison class does not care about numbers. Here is the code:

```
public class TreeNodeSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var tx = x as TreeNode;
        var ty = y as TreeNode;

        return string.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text);
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

The first child node (Debug...) is ok, but my problem is why on earth "HBM\D10" is sorted before "HBM\D7" and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting . You may need to strip out everything else though to get their solution to work - as they sort either numerically or alphabetically.

If it's a dynamic filename, you may be best using a regex to just match the parts you want to sort by.

Answer (score 9):

If portability is not an issue, you can p/invoke [StrCmpLogicalW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx). This function is used by the Windows shell to sort the file names it displays:

```
public class TreeNodeSorter : IComparer
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var tx = x as TreeNode;
        var ty = y as TreeNode;

        return StrCmpLogicalW(tx.Text, ty.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends how 'clean' of a solution you want really. The odds are, if you implement your own using the method at DotNetPearls and a regex, you'll probably learn more and possibly reuse it.

Comment: I've just found that `StrCmpLogicalW` hangs if both parameters are null, so check for nulls may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the char '1' is less that the char '7. This is becuase the strings are compared one char at a time.

An easy fix would be to incude padded 0's at the begininning of the string, like:

```
D04
D07
D10
D11
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonable pattern to extract the number ( I guess something like @"\D\d+"  ) use this to remove the number from your label, then if the label are equals return the two number difference as comparison.